# Android : WakefulIntentService does not release wake lock

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Here is the code that I use in `BroadCastReceiver`:

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        // SMSReceivedService is my custom service, extends from Service class  
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SMSReceivedService.class);
        myIntent.putExtras(intent);
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, myIntent);
    }
}

public class SMSReceivedService extends extends WakefulIntentService {
    public SMSReceivedService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        // main code here
    }
}
```

Here is the piece of code that's inside `WakefulIntentService`

```
synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (lockStatic == null) {
        PowerManager mgr =
                (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, NAME);
        lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }
    return(lockStatic);
}

public static void sendWakefulWork(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    getLock(ctxt.getApplicationContext()).acquire();
    ctxt.startService(i);
}
```

As who has used `WakefullIntentService` will know that, just call `sendWakefulWork` and `WakefullIntentService` will do all stuff in the background. But in code above, `WakefullIntentService` just hold wake lock, but after finish, I don't see any code that release this lock. Is it true ? So it will affect the Android User. Please give me ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are using my `WakefulIntentService`, or you invented your own with the same name. If you are using my `WakefulIntentService`, the lock is released in `onHandleIntent()`, as you can tell by reading [the source code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/wakeful/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/WakefulIntentService.java).

Comment: Yes, I'm using yours `WakefulIntentService` class :D There is a point that I can't understand : because I'm calling a static method (so don't initialize object for this class), `WakefulIntentService` still run as an Intent service ? (Meaning : it will run its circle life, run through `onHandleIntent()` ... Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt: `sendWakefulWork()` calls `startService()`, as you can see in the source code that you posted.

Comment: I have edited my post, that how I use `WakefulIntentService`. I think something I use wrong here, because when I debug, I see that program doesn't go through `onHandleIntent()`. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe my main code in my custom service should put in `WakefulIntentService`, right ?

Comment: @hqt: `SmsReceivedService` needs to inherit from `WakefulIntentService`.

Comment: I have change class `SmsReceivedService` extends `WakefulIntentService`, but as I notice, the constructor is : `public WakefulIntentService(String name)`. This constructor contains parameter String. but as I use : `Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SMSReceivedService.class);` No way to know name parameter. I think that why when I run program, I meet exception : `unable instantiate service` I have edited my post to show that I change inherit of class service :(

Comment: @hqt: You should read the documentation for `IntentService` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and the `IntentService` portion of the `Service` guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService). You might also consider examining the sample code that accompanies `WakefulIntentService`, such as https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/demo/AppService.java

Comment: @hqt: As all of the above will show you, you need to implement a public zero-argument constructor on your service, that chains to the superclass' one-argument constructor, where you supply whatever name you want to use for your `IntentService`.

Comment: oh. thanks :) Everything now works as I expected (and as we discussed before). Talking with author is always great :D Thanks for helping me tonight :)

Comment: all your answers, I read post by post, always help me figure out something :D